# tslint integration with gradle

Tags: gradle, tslint

We have a requirement of using tslint as a code analisys tool as we are using TypeSript for development.
I searched on many forums to find out how to integrate tslint with gradle and could not find a good solution for the problem.

Could anybody please tell me how do I achieve that.

> How do I integrate tslint with gradle and generate the report like we do in case of sonarqube and gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Write a task of type `Exec` that calls the tslint executable with the parameters that are suitable for you. If you need more specific help, please ask more specific questions after trying to do it.